# Unable to get data from 'Management' view in Discussions List

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, jsom, community-site

I am working `Community` sites in `SharePoint 2013`.

I  have a requirement where I want to fetch the discussions from the `Management` view and display but I am unable to do so.

I have used the following query:

> ```
>    <View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ReplyCount'
>    Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy></Query></View>
> ```

but the required data is not being fetched.
I want to fetch the data from the `Replies` column here but it is not being retrieved.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try using Recursive scope , please check the below query

```
<View Scope="Recursive">
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='ReplyCount'
   Ascending='FALSE'/>
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
</View>
```